# Parsing JSON does not work for the first time

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a dataTask on a separate swift class file to retrieve some data into an array:

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray {

    let resourceIDs = NSMutableArray()
    var result = NSArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count {

        let jsonElement : NSDictionary = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let resourceID = jsonElement["ResourceID"]!

        resourceIDs.add(resourceID)
    }

    result = resourceIDs
    print(result) // data is stored
    VC.resourceIDs = result //pass the object's NSArray to the ViewController's NSArray
}
else {

    print("Could not parse JSON!")
}
```

When I try to call my button function **for the first time**, my ViewController's NSArray `resourceIDs` does not receive anything. When I call my button function again, the array is then populated.

```
@IBAction func btnCheckAvailability(_ sender: UIButton) {

    showOverlayOnTask(message: "Please wait...")

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: startDate)
    let time = timeFormatter.string(from: startDate)
    CheckAvailableModel().checkAvailable(resourceType: resourceType!, startDate: date, startTime: time, VC: self)

    if (resourceIDs.count > 0) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in

                print(self.resourceIDs)
            })
        }
    }
    else {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { action in

                print("No available resources")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the array from my view controller to populate when I call the button function for the first time?

Comment: Why are you using `NS[Mutable]Array` and `NS[Mutable]Dictionary` in Swift instead of Swift native arrays and dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the resourceIDs, you're not updating your ViewController. You should call a completion block or something to inform your VC, or in the worst case add a `DidSet` to that property.
`VC.resourceIDs = result`

By the other hand, you can optimize better your functions.

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]] {
    let resourceIDs: [String] = []

    for jsonElement in jsonResult {
        let resourceID = jsonElement["ResourceID"]!
        resourceIDs.append(resourceID)
    }
    VC.resourceIDs = resourceIDs
}
else {
    print("Could not parse JSON!")
}
```

Also, in your `btnCheckAvailability` function check the retain cycles in the closures.